# Is there any way to convert the string - 'Light travels faster than sound' into 'LIGHT travels faster than SOUND' in Python

Tags: python, string, indexing, slice

I want to convert `Light travels faster than sound` into `LIGHT travels faster than SOUND` in Python.

Here is what I have tried

```
s = "Light travels faster than sound.This is why some people appear bright until you hear them speak"
s.replace('Light', 'LIGHT')
s.replace('sound', 'SOUND')
print(s)
```

Comment: Strings are immutable. `replace` returns a new string

Comment: Thankyou . I will keep this thing in mind